# Arduino Header file "No matching function for call to"

Tags: c++, arduino

I've been working on an Arduino project. Until recently I had everything in located in the one .ino file. I have decided to restructure my code and move my classes to their own files.

My problem is when I copy my Sensor class to a .h file, and include it, my program is unable to compile, and I get the following error.

If I copy it back to the .ino file, then everything works perfectly again.

```
In file included from GardenSensor.ino:1:0:
C:\Users\Brenton\AppData\Local\Temp\build5441194172372520295.tmp\Sensor.h: At global scope:
C:\Users\Brenton\AppData\Local\Temp\build5441194172372520295.tmp\Sensor.h:8:14: error: expected ')' before 'sensorType'
  Sensor(byte sensorType, byte sensorID) : _sensorType(sensorType), _sensorID(sensorID) {}
              ^
C:\Users\Brenton\AppData\Local\Temp\build5441194172372520295.tmp\Sensor.h:14:2: error: 'byte' does not name a type
  byte sensorID() { return _sensorID; }
  ^
C:\Users\Brenton\AppData\Local\Temp\build5441194172372520295.tmp\Sensor.h:15:2: error: 'byte' does not name a type
  byte sensorType() { return _sensorType; }
  ^
C:\Users\Brenton\AppData\Local\Temp\build5441194172372520295.tmp\Sensor.h:18:2: error: 'byte' does not name a type
  byte _sensorType;
  ^
C:\Users\Brenton\AppData\Local\Temp\build5441194172372520295.tmp\Sensor.h:19:2: error: 'byte' does not name a type
  byte _sensorID;
  ^
GardenSensor.ino: In constructor 'AnalogSensor::AnalogSensor(byte, byte, byte)':
GardenSensor.ino:5:103: error: no matching function for call to 'Sensor::Sensor(byte&, byte&)'
GardenSensor.ino:5:103: note: candidates are:
In file included from GardenSensor.ino:1:0:
C:\Users\Brenton\AppData\Local\Temp\build5441194172372520295.tmp\Sensor.h:6:7: note: Sensor::Sensor()
 class Sensor {
       ^
C:\Users\Brenton\AppData\Local\Temp\build5441194172372520295.tmp\Sensor.h:6:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
C:\Users\Brenton\AppData\Local\Temp\build5441194172372520295.tmp\Sensor.h:6:7: note: Sensor::Sensor(const Sensor&)
C:\Users\Brenton\AppData\Local\Temp\build5441194172372520295.tmp\Sensor.h:6:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
GardenSensor.ino: In constructor 'SensorArray::SensorArray(unsigned int)':
GardenSensor.ino:16:35: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
GardenSensor.ino: In function 'void printAllSensors()':
GardenSensor.ino:61:29: error: 'class Sensor' has no member named 'sensorID'
GardenSensor.ino:66:30: error: 'class Sensor' has no member named 'sensorID'
no matching function for call to 'Sensor::Sensor(byte&, byte&)'
```

My Sensor class

```
class Sensor {
public:
    Sensor(byte sensorType, byte sensorID) : _sensorType(sensorType), _sensorID(sensorID) {}

    virtual ~Sensor() {}

    virtual unsigned int getReading() = 0;

    byte sensorID() { return _sensorID; }
    byte sensorType() { return _sensorType; }

private:
    byte _sensorType;
    byte _sensorID;
};
```

Thank you

Comment: Where is `byte` defined?

Comment: According to the official docs, it's one of the types included in the arduino environment.
http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage
Other classes using this type are not having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#include <Arduino.h>` in your external code files.